# Merge and export two types of lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long list of dates and a list of numbers. I like two put them into one list/array with dates in one column and number in the second column and export it to a txt file.what can be the best solution? here is an example:

```
def perdelta(start, end, delta):
    curr = start
    while curr < end:
        yield curr
        curr += delta
dates=[result for result in perdelta(date(2013, 1, 1), date(2013, 12, 
28), timedelta(days=1))]
for x in dates:
    dates_str.append(str(x))
```

which returns for example:

```
>>> dates_str[1]
'2013-01-02'
```

and a list of number:

```
num=range(0,361)
```

and I want to have dates_str in one column and num in a second column and export them to txt/csv file. I'm using python 3. Thanks

Comment: Why not use the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library?

Comment: Thanks! problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments that this might work better using a tabular form such as the pandas library, for example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"dates":dates, "num":range(0,361)})
df.to_csv("my_csv.csv", index=False)
```

This assumes your lists have equal length